# How to get DynamoTableItems type output to an IEnumeral list

Tags: json, linq, asp.net-core

I am using this [github](https://github.com/donbavand/DynamoDBDemo) dynamodb that works great. My front end is looking for a different format from the GET.

This is what I receive from NET backend

```
{"items":[{"id":3,"replyDateTime":"63668789020007000","body":"ilovelife","title":"mytittle","creator":"me"},{"id":4,"replyDateTime":"63668789020007900","body":"ilovelife","title":"mytittle","creator":"me"},{"id":17,"replyDateTime":"63669789320007900","body":"ilovelife","title":"mytittle","creator":"me"},{"id":5,"replyDateTime":"63668799020007900","body":"ilovelife","title":"mytittle","creator":"me"}]}
```

I would like to change it to this format

```
[{"postId":42,"creator":"Martin","title":"se","body":"dfadsf","dt":"2020-05-11T01:14:30.757"},{"postId":41,"creator":"Martin","title":"mickey mouse","body":"i love life","dt":"2020-05-11T00:57:17.609"}]
```

It looks like a dictionary but dictionary functions do not work on the DynamoTableItems

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/donbavand/DynamoDBDemo/blob/master/DynamoDb.Libs/DynamoDb/GetItem.cs#L29, it appears to be a `List`. Why not use `Select` to convert the items in List into the expected representation?

Comment: @ArunM thanks for the hint. Select was the key.

Answer (score 0):

I used linq to convert the response to a list that matches what the front end was expecting.

```
        {
            // response is a list
            var response = await _getItem.GetItems(id);
            Item[] list = response.Items.Select(c => new Item
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                ReplyDateTime = c.ReplyDateTime,
                Body = c.Body,
                Title = c.Title,
                Creator = c.Creator

            }
                ).ToArray();

            return Ok(list);
        }
```